# .append and .html in one line jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to .append to a div and pass the value on as html using jQuery

I want to pass a hidden `<input type=hidden....>` append and sending it as .html

```
$('#here').append(va_lue).html();
```

Hoping you guys understand now

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Pass what value on? The html of the div after the append, or the html that _was appended_?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the value" there, Jean. Is it the "html" source of what you appended? The "html" of the whole `<div>`?  the jQuery object representing the whole `<div>`?

Comment: @point check the q in a minute

Comment: What do you mean by, "sending it"?  Sending what?  Sending where?

Comment: @pointy to a <div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's still not clear what you are asking, but I *think* it's this:

```
$('#yourDivId').append($('<input/>')
  .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'nameOfParameter', 'value': 'your value'})
);
```

That will add a new `<input>` tag to a div whose "id" is "yourDivId".  The input field will be of type "hidden", and will have whatever name and value you want.

If you have a block of HTML for your input field, then you would do something like this (as @psychotik already wrote):

```
var inputFieldHtml = "<input type='hidden' name='whatever' value='balloons'>";
$('#yourDivId').append($(inputFieldHtml));
```

Answer (score 1):

This?
`var newHtml= $(newHtml).appendTo( $('#placeToInsert') ).html();`